Concatenate values under into a new column
Consider this df:

    data = {'ID': [1071.0, 1072.0, nan, 1074.0, 1076.0, nan, nan, nan, 1077.0], 
'Name Type': ['Primary Name', 'Primary Name', 'Also Known As', 'Primary Name', 'Primary Name', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Primary Name'], 
'Surname': ['Brown', 'Red', 'R', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Pipi', 'Poopa', 'Peep', 'Orange']}

There are many more columns that have info in the rows with Primary Name but empty with akas. I need to concatenate values under each Primary Name - Surname if they are Low Quality AKA or Also Known as and achieve this dataframe:


This is not how I would recommend setting up the data. I would probably have two datasets with A matching ID and then Left Join the table. That being said, here is the code for your situation.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ID': [1071.0, 1072.0, np.nan, 1074.0, 1076.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1077.0], 
        'Name Type': ['Primary Name', 'Primary Name', 'Also Known As', 'Primary Name', 'Primary Name', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Low Quality AKA', 'Primary Name'], 
        'Surname': ['Brown', 'Red', 'R', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Pipi', 'Poopa', 'Peep', 'Orange']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Forward fill the IDs and keep only rows with 'Primary Name'
df['ID'] = df['ID'].ffill()
primary_names = df[df['Name Type'] == 'Primary Name'].copy()

# Group by ID and aggregate the surnames for AKA names
akas = df[df['Name Type'].str.contains('AKA')].groupby('ID')['Surname'].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x)).reset_index()
akas.rename(columns={'Surname': 'AKAs'}, inplace=True)

# Combine data
result = pd.merge(primary_names, akas, on='ID', how='left')

# Put empty string in AKAs col
result['AKAs'] = result['AKAs'].fillna('')

# Select and reorder columns to match the desired output
result = result[['ID', 'Name Type', 'Surname', 'AKAs']]

print(result)


Given this dataframe df as input:
       ID        Name Type Surname
0  1071.0     Primary Name   Brown
1  1072.0     Primary Name     Red
2     NaN    Also Known As       R
3  1074.0     Primary Name   Green
4  1076.0     Primary Name  Purple
5     NaN  Low Quality AKA    Pipi
6     NaN  Low Quality AKA   Poopa
7     NaN  Low Quality AKA    Peep
8  1077.0     Primary Name  Orange

You can use this approach:
df_aka_filter = df["ID"].isna()

df["ID"] = df["ID"].ffill()

df_aka = df[df_aka_filter]
df_aka = (
    df_aka.groupby("ID", as_index=False)
    .agg(lambda x: ";".join(x))
    .drop(columns="Name Type")
    .rename(columns={"Surname": "AKAs"})
)

df = pd.merge(df[~df_aka_filter], df_aka, on="ID", how="left")

       ID     Name Type Surname             AKAs
0  1071.0  Primary Name   Brown              NaN
1  1072.0  Primary Name     Red                R
2  1074.0  Primary Name   Green              NaN
3  1076.0  Primary Name  Purple  Pipi;Poopa;Peep
4  1077.0  Primary Name  Orange              NaN

